# GWT Junit is failing after upgrade to 2.8.2

Tags: junit, gwt, compiler-errors

I have been using GWT 2.4 for one of my projects. Recently, I have upgraded the GWT version to 2.8.2 and the existing Junit is failing for no reason. Please help me troubleshoot the issue.

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.769 sec
------------- Standard Error -----------------
Unknown argument: -standardsMode
Google Web Toolkit 2.8.2
------------- ---------------- ---------------

Testcase: testOne took 0.537 sec
Caused an ERROR Error processing shell arguments
com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitFatalLaunchException: Error processing shell arguments
at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.getUnitTestShell(JUnitShell.java:696)
at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTest(JUnitShell.java:682)
at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.runTest(GWTTestCase.java:421)
at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.run(GWTTestCase.java:247)


 [exec] -test.dev:
 [exec]     [mkdir] Created dir: C:\gitrepos\Python\petroApps\isdBuild\JDK_1.8\isdApps\topaz\gui\impl\web\client\gwt\pres\reports\htmlunit.dev
 [exec]     [junit] WARNING: multiple versions of ant detected in path for junit 
 [exec]     [junit]          jar:file:/C:/gitrepos/Python/petroApps/isdMWare/buildTools/apache/ant/V1.9.6/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
 [exec]     [junit]      and jar:file:/C:/gitrepos/Python/petroApps/isdMWare/java/apis/google/gwt/V2.8.2/lib/gwt-dev.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
 [exec]     [junit] Running com.verifone.isd.topaz.gui.impl.web.client.gwt.pres.POSPresTestSuite
 [exec]     [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.769 sec

 [exec] BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

In GWT 2.7.0 (RC1) the `-standardsMode` has been removed.

"Removed flags: -standardsMode, -nostandardsMode, -quirksMode. (GWTTestCase tests are always run in an HTML page in standards mode.)"

See: [GWT Release Notes](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html)

To solve your problem, remove the argument.